# software for editing 2 images at the same time

Tags: software-rec, images

I am looking to find if possible a tool which can take a area screenshot and let me edit it like so:
[image: image with boxes]

however I also want an image like this to be created simultaneously after editing the first image:
[image: image with frames]

So what I am looking for is a tool which can do the two tasks at the same time and save them as seperate images.

Comment: Try this: Open your screenshot/background in inkscape. Right click and select "Lock Object". Use the rectangle tool to create your rectangles in the desired positions. Select all your rectangles (Ctrl+A) click the colors in Button to set fill color and shift-click them to set the border. Export both variations as PNG using File->"Export Png Image".

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.